# Стилистическая окраска есть?

Tags: стилистика

Какая работа проводится органами местного самоуправления по обеспечению возможности организации обучения детей в общеобразовательных организациях в одну смену?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  **Стилистической окраски нет у нейтрального стиля.** Он не имеет признаков функциональных стилей (публицистический; научный; официально-деловой; художественный; разговорный), а также входит в ряд  *высокий – нейтральный – сниженный стили.*

Каждый из названных стилей имеет свои лексические, морфологические и синтаксические особенности, **что и составляет  стилистическую окраску текста.**

2) **Какая работа проводится органами местного самоуправления по обеспечению возможности организации обучения детей в общеобразовательных организациях в одну смену?**

Приведенный пример относится **к официально-деловому стилю по следующим признакам:** профессиональная терминология, речевые штампы, отглагольные существительные, пассивные конструкции, прямой порядок слов;  словосочетания в родительном падеже.

Функциональные стили  https://vseorechi.ru/ritorika/stilistika-rechi/funkcionalnye-stili-rechi.html

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом зададимся вопросом, что такое стилистическая окраска.

> стилистическая окраска — ед.   В лексической стилистике: экспрессивные свойства языковой единицы, накладывающиеся на ее основное, или предметно логическое, значение. *парус (нейтральная окраска) ветрило (возвышенная окраска); ударить (нейтральная окраска) шибануть… …   Учебный словарь стилистических терминов (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1602/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Получается, что стилистическая окраска есть всегда (если окраска нейтральная, то некоторые говорят, что окраски нет), вопрос лишь в том какова она и какие виды окраски существуют. На мой взгляд, для стиля приведенного предложения подходит определение канцелярский. Особенно режет ухо набор из пяти идущих в ряд существительных, причем четыре подряд стоят в родительном падеже: **обеспечению возможности организации обучения детей**.

> § 204. [Нанизывание одинаковых форм](https://info.wikireading.ru/69473)
>   1. Затрудняет понимание текста скопление одинаковых падежных форм. Чаще всего встречается нанизывание родительных падежей, например: «В целях лучшей постановки дела повышения теоретического уровня…»; «Для решения задачи ускорения подъема…»; «Закон о перестройке школы был принят в целях дальнейшего улучшения качества воспитания подрастающего поколения»; «Для выполнения требования устранения отставания производства деталей намечены конкретные меры».
>   При правке отглагольные существительные обычно заменяют инфинитивами или другими конструкциями, распространенные обороты – придаточными предложениями, устраняют лишние слова и т. д., например: Чтобы повысить теоретический уровень…; С целью ускорить подъём…